# instatiate class variable in suscribe method angular2

Tags: angular2-services

I am trying to instantiate a class variable in subscribe method.

```
class Emp{
    val : Array<EmpClass> =[];
    getEmp() : EmpClass[] {
        this.http.get<EmpMyClass[]>(this.targetURL).subscribe(data => this.val = data);
        alert(this.val.count)
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

This method retrieves data (list of json object) from server. It triggers when button "Retrieve" is clicked and renders all object in list on UI.
I have another method that updates the DB(add new employee object).

Expectation -> I add an employee object. After when I click "Retrieve", the updated result should come on screen.

Actual behaviour -> If I click "Retrieve" for the first time, 0 result is rendered (because list is empty, I think method returned the list before the subscribe call finished). If I click "Retrieve" a second time (after a gap of 1 sec), the correct result is rendered.

is there a way I can make sure the list is returned only after subscribe is complete i.e on the first click of "Retrieve" button.

Note: I also tried another way

```
getEmp() {
    let   v: Array<EmpMyClass> = [];
    this.http.get<EmpMyClass[]>(this.targetURL).subscribe(data => v = data , () => console.log(), () => this.meth(v));
}
meth(em: EmpMyClass[]) {
    this.val = em;
}
getVal(): EmpMyClass[] {
    return this.val;
}
```

I first called `getEmp()` assuming it will instantiate the `val` variable and then called `getVal()` to get updated list but the result is still the same.

I have read similar posts but still not able to overcome this scenario.